# Not possible to move vertices on Z axis

Tags: edit-mode

I created a mesh by using the mirror modifier. I cannot move the vertices of that object on the Z axis after applying the modifier.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the best place to upload files for this forum btw?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have scaled your object incredibly small and to zero on the Z-Axis. If you <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in *Object Mode* (to remove scale) and then either zoom out, or hit the <kbd>Home</kbd> you will see your model again and can edit if further in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: Thats true, I selected all vertices and pressed S -> Z -> 0.

Answer (score 4):

You have your object scaled to 0 on the Z axis.

Tab into Object mode and in the Property Region area to the right of the 3DView, below Scale, set Z to a non-zero value.